# plus and non-plus for id-beginner wonder

Tags: android

I am an Android beginner and I don't understand what exactly the plus (+) before `id` reference means.
The tutorials I found on the web only say it is for `new id reference` and non-plus definition means it references the defined `id`. Could you offer an example to clarify my non-understanding of this tiny detail I am cracking my brain to get it right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:id="@+id/your_id"` implies that SDK will generate `R.id.your_id` integer resource (you can check the auto-generated R.java file).

A refernce on `your_id` without "+" (`android:id="@id/your_id"`) is just a "pointer" to an already generated resource `R.id.your_id`. So in order to use it you should have already defined it somewhere within the code.

So, as a simple conclusion: "+" stands for addition/creation of an id, without "+" stands for using already created id.